# Как в Linq to entity выделисть строку где есть null обьект

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
var delete = db.Users.Where(t => t.Name == null);
db.Users.RemoveRange(delete);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Я через linq выбираю в бд те строки где поле name равно null, и удаляю их, но в самой базе данных они не удаляются. Теперь самое странное, я нашёл что sql помечает null обьекты как "NotExistingActionType", и поэтому чтобы выбрать null обьекты нужно сравнивать обьект не с null а именно с "NotExistingActionType". Но так тоже не работает, частично. Я решил поэксперементировать, и создал запрос на вывод строк где поле Name != "NotExistingActionType", и мне выводит все строки кроме null. Но вот на этом моменте у меня вообще сломался мозг. Если я делаю запрос на вывод строк где name == "NotExistingActionType", то мне не выводит ниодной строки, хотя по логике должно было вывести все строки где name == null в самой таблице. Ну так вот сам вопрос. Как в запросе указать обьект null в таблице, и есть ли ещё такие странности в linq to entity?(Использую Entity Framework core 5)

Comment: Два года не писал на c# и могу ошибиться но по-моему Where( t => t.Name == DBNull.Value )

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Неа, не работает((

Comment: `Name == null` должно работать. | Как именно была создана БД?

Comment: Я смог решить проблему. Это очень смешно))))) Короче, я только начинаю учить entity, и подошёл к изучению миграций, и решил создать свою мигрцию где сначала в таблице поле Name может иметь тип null, а потом добавить ей [required] и обновить таблицу с новой миграцией. Но при обновлении таблицы с новой миграцией мне написало что у меня есть поля где Name null а так нельзя. Ну я и решил удалить все строки где name null, через код. И так получилось что он не хотел удалять строки null потому-что в классе таблицы name был [required], я его убрал и всё заработало. Хотя странно.